# How can I get my all photolibrary images from iPad in to an array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, nsmutablearray, photolibrary

How can I get my all photolibrary images from iPad in to an array.

I need `NSMutableArray *myArray = "All photoLibrary images"`

Can any one please help me to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Study the ALAssetsLibrary framework: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722

Comment: hi @Christina have you solved this problem? can you share the answer?